# How to generate NUUID in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, guid, uuid

As the title states, I'm looking for a way to generate a `NUUID` ([.NET Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compatible id) in a script for the mongodb shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage:

```
NUUID(uuid())
```

The `uuid` generator is based on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/1041735):

```
function uuid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```

The conversion from `uuid` to mongodb `BinData` is based on [uuidhelpers.js](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js):

```
function HexToBase64(hex) {
    var base64Digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    var base64 = "";
    var group;
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i += 6) {
        group = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 6), 16);
        base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 18) & 0x3f];
        base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 12) & 0x3f];
        base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 6) & 0x3f];
        base64 += base64Digits[group & 0x3f];
    }
    group = parseInt(hex.substr(30, 2), 16);
    base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 2) & 0x3f];
    base64 += base64Digits[(group << 4) & 0x3f];
    base64 += "==";
    return base64;
}

function NUUID(uuid) {
    var hex = uuid.replace(/[{}-]/g, ""); // remove extra characters
    var a = hex.substr(6, 2) + hex.substr(4, 2) + hex.substr(2, 2) + hex.substr(0, 2);
    var b = hex.substr(10, 2) + hex.substr(8, 2);
    var c = hex.substr(14, 2) + hex.substr(12, 2);
    var d = hex.substr(16, 16);
    hex = a + b + c + d;
    var base64 = HexToBase64(hex);
    return new BinData(3, base64);
}
```

Comment: Will you care to explain what is `BinData()` I found nothing like it in javascript

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/BinData/

Comment: Can you please define `NUUID` I am not able find much info about it, like the algorithm and the format. ?